# How to bring user back to original URL after login?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, next.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm using PassportJS to authenticate users through Google on a NextJS app. So far, I've gotten the authentication part working fine. However, Google insists that I register with it a **callback URL** or a list thereof, and redirect users only to one of those after the login is successful.

What I want is to make it dynamic. So if the user is on https://www.schandillia.com/blog/somepage and hits the **sign in through Google** button, he first goes to https://www.schandillia.com/auth/google, then to https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount. Here, once he signs in successfully (or even unsuccessfully), I want him to be taken back to https://www.schandillia.com/blog/somepage, rather than some static redirect page. My repo is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web and the scripts in question are as follows:

**/server/server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import next from 'next';

import authRoutes from '../routes/auth-routes';


const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

dotenv.config();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  // Custom middleware
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.use(bodyParser.json());
  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  server.use(cookieParser());

  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Auth routes
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.use('/auth', authRoutes);
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Default route (not to be edited)
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------
  server.get('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res));
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------------

  // Express: Listener
  server.listen(process.env.WEB_PORT, () => {
    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    console.log(`>> Listening on port ${process.env.WEB_PORT}`);
    /* eslint-enable no-console */
  });
}).catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```

**/routes/auth-routes.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import passport from 'passport';
import passportSetup from '../config/passport-setup';

const router = express.Router();

// auth login
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.send('login...');
});
// auth logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.send('log out...');
});
// auth with Google
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
  scope: ['profile']
}));

module.exports = router;
```

**/config/passport-setup.js**

```
import passport from 'passport';
import GoogleStrategy from 'passport-google-oauth20';

dotenv.config();

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy({
    // options for google strategy
    callbackURL: 'https://www.schandillia.com/auth/google/redirect',
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  }, () => {
    // passport callback function
  }),
);
```

And then, as is customary in the NextJS world, I have my pages defined as JSX files in `/pages/`. The sign-in functionality itself is through a modal dialog available on all pages through the `Navbar.jsx` component rather than a dedicated login page.

So, how do I pass on the current URL value from the client to the `/config/passport-setup.js` script dynamically? Also, does Google have a restriction on the number of URLs one may add to the callback list?

**P.S.**: I tried using [universal-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/universal-cookie) to set a cookie (as suggested by n. m. in a comment below) in `pages/index.jsx`:

`const cookies = new Cookies();`

Then set the value in `componentDidMount()`:

```
pageURL = process.env.BASE_URL + Router.pathname; // https://schandillia.com/
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('pageURL', pageURL);
```

This successfully sets the cookie. Then to retrieve the same, I do the following in my `server.js`:

```
// Cookie
  server.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // check if client sent cookie
    const pageURL = req.cookies.pageURL;
    if (pageURL === undefined) {
      console.log('NO COOKIE FOUND!!');
    }
    else {
      console.log('COOKIE FOUND!!!!', pageURL);
    }
    next();
  });
```

This system works fine. Except during client-side routing. Since the server only gets called when the page is loaded initially or refreshed, it fails to receive the cookie when the routing happens strictly on the browser. Any workaround?

Comment: Set them a cookie.

Comment: I tried cookies but it doesn't entirely help the situation. Please see my update in the question?